# Web Api Controller Authorize - where are these roles defined?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, authorize-attribute

I have gone through the Web Api guide for Authentication and Authorization. I have a follow up question:

If I use below policy for authorize:

```
// Restrict by role:
[Authorize(Roles="Administrators")]
public class ValuesController : ApiController { }
```

Where do I set these Roles ?
I presume, it is some central system where I can go and create a new group and add users in that?

Answer (score 0):

In the database. Asuming you're using ASP.NET Identity 2.0, it will create a database schema for you (by default using LocalDB, but you can point the connection string to SQL Server Express if you look). It comes with a Roles table. You can then attach this role to the user.

Since you seem to be looking for some kind of admin interface, check out [ThinkTecture IdentityManager](http://brockallen.com/2014/04/09/introducing-thinktecture-identitymanager/) by Brock Allen. I'm not entirely sure it has role management, but there's a good chance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manage the roles through code you can have a look at the `System.Web.Security.Roles` class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles(v=vs.100).aspx

It has methods for creating new roles, adding users to roles etc.